# Precompile assets on Rails 3.2.3, rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2.3 app and on my local machine, it runs fine.

The problem is, when I push to Heroku, I get a rake aborted! message when precompiling assets. On the local machine, I get.

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/victory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby /Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
File to import not found or unreadable: custom.
Load path: /Users/victory/Documents/chinchin
  (in /Users/victory/Documents/chinchin/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):1
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:64:in `rescue in import'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:42:in `import'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:25:in `imported_file'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:149:in `rescue in visit_import'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:154:in `visit_import'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:27:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:39:in `with_environment'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:26:in `visit_children'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:47:in `visit_root'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/engine.rb:299:in `_render'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-3.1.18/lib/sass/engine.rb:246:in `render'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/lib/sass/rails/compressor.rb:8:in `compress'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:243:in `block in css_compressor='
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:20:in `block in compile'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/victory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125...]
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victory/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/victory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

In my application.css, I have

```
@import "custom";
@import "user";
@import "static_pages";
```

I contain all of my css in custom but user and static_pages is still left blank. Even if I take the first line out, the error occurs for user or static_pages.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Everything works fine on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure those other CSS files have been committed to git.

Comment: That does not seem to be the cause. I have narrowed down that the cause has something to do with ActiveAdmin. Still can't figure it out, though

Comment: I am in the same problem as you. Have yo figured it out yet?